# Compute det(A) given a function A

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose A is a 3×3 matrix and A =
1/3
$u_1\cdot uT_1$ +
1/4
$u_2\cdot uT_2$ +
2/5
$u_3\cdot uT_3$ with

$uT_1 = (0, 1, −1)$

$uT_2 = (1, 2, 2)$

$u_3 = (−2,1/2,1/2)$

> Compute det(A).

I know how to find determinants of 3x3 matricies, but I'm confused how to start this one given this function. Do I just use the given transposes to find $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ and then use those as column vectors in the matrix?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: I tried to edit this but I'm really not 100% sure what the OP meant by some of this...

Comment: @GregoryGrant I gave it some moments of attention, yet I also couldn't understand what's going on there.

Comment: My main confusion is what is meant by $T$ and what's the difference between $u1$ and $uT1$...

Comment: The three column vectors $u_1^T$, $u_2^T$, $u_3^T$ you have are orthogonal to each other with norm $\sqrt{2}$, $3$ and $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$ respectively. If you use the
corresponding "unit vectors" as a basis, you obtain a diagonal matrix...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion the uT1 was the transpose of u1. I'm confused on how you obtain a diagonal matrix from the unit vectors.

Comment: Sorry, the three $u_i^T$ should be row instead of column vectors. If you use them to form a $3\times 3$ matrix whose  $k^{th}$ row is $u_k^T$ and let $\Delta$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $1/3, 1/4, 2/5$. Your $A$ will be  equal to $M^T \Delta M$. If you normalize the 3 row vectors before you build a matrix $M_{new}$, $M_{new}$  will become a orthogonal matrix. This corresponds to a change of basis to the one defined by the 3 unit vectors. If you multiply the $i^{th}$ diagonal entry of $\Delta$ by $|u_i|^2$, the new $\Delta_{new}$ will be your matrix $A$ in the new basis.